# Como pegar evento do Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Estou usando Owl Carousel na imagem grande, as miniaturas do lado esquerdo devem funcionar como controler também, mas eu não sei como pegar o evento de 'mudar imagem' do slide. Como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Difícil vai ser pela miniatura selecionar exatamente a mesma imagem no carousel. O que você já tentou?

Comment: @Guerra eu consegui selecionar a imagem que está ativa e ativar a mesma da miniatura, mas não muda conforme o carousel porque falta colocar o evento rs

Comment: Coloque o código que usou para vermos, voce pode fazer com javascript puro tambem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse método tem na documentação, veja:

http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/urlhashnav.html#seven

`URLhashListener:true`

`startPosition: 'URLHash'`

Só implementar.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    loop:false,
    center:true,
    margin:10,
    URLhashListener:true, // ESSE 
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash' // E ESSE
});
```

Na `div.item`você tem que ter colocar um `data-hash` com um nome único.

Tipo:

```
<div class="item" data-hash="foto-um"> IMG </div>
<div class="item" data-hash="foto-dois"> IMG </div>
<div class="item" data-hash="foto-tres"> IMG </div>
```

Daí nas imagens miniaturas você coloca um `<a href="#foto-um">`.

```
<a href="#foto-um"><img></a>
<a href="#foto-dois"><img></a>
<a href="#foto-tres"><img></a>
```

Comment: parece que o script está calculando errado, o "#foto-um" seleciona o "#foto-sete" e assim por diante, mas os controlers do owl-carousel estão normais começando pelo primeiro item

Comment: Deve ser por causa do Loop. Desativa ele com `loop: false`. Ou já está desativado ?